# Что означает "член и его формы" в терминологии Щербы от 1929 года?

Tags: значение-слов, недопустимая-метка

Что такое "член" из цитаты ниже в современной лингвистической терминологии?

> Если человек ставит себе цель ... научиться разбираться ... во всяком тексте с помощью словаря, то он должен ... выучить вспомогательные глаголы и их спряжение, **член** и его формы (если они есть), местоимения, предлоги и союзы, понять, как можно в тексте узнавать глаголы, какие различаются глагольные формы и какие главнейшие признаки числа и падежей, если они различаются в данном языке. 
> === Л.В. Щерба. Как надо изучать иностранные языки, 1929.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из работы Щербы *«О частях речи в русском языке»*:

> **Член** европейских языков - является основным признаком существительного: нем. **handeln** — 'действовать', **das Handeln** - 'действование'.

Похоже на то, что ***член*** у  Щербы = ***артикль*** (в современной терминологии).

---

**Для справки**

> **артикль**
>
> (*франц*. article от *лат*. articulus — **член**)…
>
> *Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976.*
>
> https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/78/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8C

---

Термин «член» в значении ‘артикль’ употреблялся в русском языке и до Щербы и был широко распространён.

См. фрагмент из *«Исторической грамматики русского языка»* Фёдора Ивановича Буслаева (первое издание которой вышло в середине 19-го века):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А этот фрагмент — из  **«Русско-французского словаря», составленного  «под общим руководством и редакцией проф. Л. В. ЩЕРБЫ»**, вышедшего в 1936 г.:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, этот фрагмент даёт однозначный ответ на заданный в этой теме вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

**[Книга](https://libcat.ru/knigi/nauka-i-obrazovanie/yazykoznanie/55700-lev-shherba-kak-nado-izuchat-inostrannye-yazyki.html#text)** Щерба Лев Владимирович. **Как надо изучать иностранные языки**

1. В Интернете встречается [такое понимание](https://author.today/post/361243) текста:
   *Выучить вспомогательные глаголы и их спряжение; **член предложения и его формы** (если есть), местоимения, предлоги и союзы.*

**Почему так** понимается термин? Члены предложения — слова или словосочетания, выполняющие в предложении определённую  **семантико-синтаксическую функцию**.

[Из учебные материалов](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/186-chlenypredlogeniya.html)

**Двойная классификация слов** — по морфологическим признакам **(части речи**) и по синтаксической функции (**члены предложения)** — более всего используется применительно **к языкам с развитой морфологией.** Нужда в ней обусловлена отсутствием **однозначного соответствия** между морфологическим классом слова и выполняемой словом синтаксической функцией.

2. Дополнение: **АРТИКЛЬ? [У Виноградова](https://old.bigenc.ru/linguistics/text/1832043):**

**АРТИ́КЛЬ** (франц. article, от лат. ***articulus***) (грамматический член), грамматический элемент, выступающий в виде **служебного слова или аффикса** и служащий для выражения **именной** определённости-неопределённости категории.

**Исторически** определённый А. восходит обычно **к указат. местоимению,** неопределённый – к неопределённому местоимению или к числительному **«один».**